# What causes the bright white area in this photo of the earth?

Tags: earth, photography

Regarding the photo of the earth [described here](http://www.reddit.com/r/spaceporn/comments/sam2o/uk_and_ireland_by_night_with_the_aurora_borealis/),

[image: photo in question]

I know that the green tinge on the left hand side is to do with the aurora borealis. What's causing the bright white light on the right hand side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken on [March 28 2012 by André Kuipers](http://www.flickr.com/photos/astro_andre/6890185644/in/photostream), the version [here](http://randelirious.blogspot.com/2012/04/andre-kuipers-photos.html) is labeled

> Amazing aurora lights and **atmospheric glare** with the countries Ireland, Netherlands, Scotland, England and Wales in the foreground.

Off to the north and east like that, it's likely refracted early sunrise. That's a **lot** of streetlights for that time of the day; likely a longish exposure to capture aurora. That'd increase sunrise glare as well.

Comment: Since the sun is not visible, then it is quite dark in the British Isles. But I agree that it is a long exposure.